# @JoinColumns to an entity who already has @JoinColumns in JAVA Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have the following configuration:

## Entity A

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "key.a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<B>  bs;

    public A() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Set<B> getBs() {
        return bs;
    }
}
```

## Entity B

```
@Entity
public class B {
    @EmbeddedId
    BKey key;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "key.b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<C> cs;

    public B() {
    }

    public B(A a) {
        this.key = new BKey(a);
    }

    public BKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Set<C> getCs() {
        return cs;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class BKey implements Serializable {
    private static final AtomicInteger ID_GEN = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Column(name = "b_id")
    int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    A a;

    public BKey() {
    }

    public BKey(A a) {
        try (Session session = DbConfig.sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            Query<Integer> query = session.createQuery(
                    "SELECT MAX(o.key.id) FROM B o",
                    Integer.class
            );
            Integer maxID = query.uniqueResult();
            ID_GEN.getAndSet(maxID == null ? 1 : maxID + 1);
        }
        this.a = a;
        id = ID_GEN.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

## Entity C

```
@Entity
public class C {
    @EmbeddedId
    CKey key;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "key.c", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<D> ds;

    public C() {
    }

    public C(B b){
        this.key = new CKey(b);
    }

    public CKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public Set<D> getDs() {
        return ds;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class CKey implements Serializable {
    private static final AtomicInteger ID_GEN = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Column(name = "c_id")
    int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "b_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id")
    })
    B b;

    public CKey() {
    }

    public CKey(B b) {
        try (Session session = DbConfig.sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            Query<Integer> query = session.createQuery(
                    "SELECT MAX(o.key.id) FROM C o",
                    Integer.class
            );
            Integer maxID = query.uniqueResult();
            ID_GEN.getAndSet(maxID == null ? 1 : maxID + 1);
        }
        this.b = b;
        id = ID_GEN.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

## Entity D

```
@Entity
public class D {
    @EmbeddedId
    DKey key;

    public D() {
    }

    public D(C c) {
        this.key = new DKey(c);
    }

    public DKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class DKey implements Serializable {
    private static final AtomicInteger ID_GEN = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Column(name = "d_id")
    int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "c_id", referencedColumnName = "c_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "b_id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", referencedColumnName = "a_id")
    })
    C c;

    public DKey() {
    }

    public DKey(C c) {
        try (Session session = DbConfig.sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            Query<Integer> query = session.createQuery(
                    "SELECT MAX(o.key.id) FROM D o",
                    Integer.class
            );
            Integer maxID = query.uniqueResult();
            ID_GEN.getAndSet(maxID == null ? 1 : maxID + 1);
        }
        this.c = c;
        id = ID_GEN.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public C getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Seems like I didn't configure the `@JoinColumns` annotation for field `c` in class `DKey` correctly, as when I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL create commands for table : D
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getTypeForEntityValue(Column.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getColumnSize(Column.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlTypeName(Column.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.StandardTableExporter.getSqlCreateStrings(StandardTableExporter.java:99)
    ... 71 more
```

What should have I done?

I have tried to configure these annotations in many different ways with no better results.
This has to be at the configuration of class `DKey` as without that class everything works fine.